# Accessing Vue Nuxt plugins in layouts using fetch()

Tags: vue.js, fetch, nuxt.js

Wanted to ask if I am doing this right, it feels clunky. I am accessing a plugin in a Nuxt layout component. I want to dynamically generate content within the layout via the new `fetch()` api.

```js
async fetch() {
  this.notifications = await this.$root.context.app.contentfulClient.getNotifications()
  this.treatments = await this.$root.context.app.contentfulClient.getTreatments()
},
```

It works as expected, but it seems a long handed way of accessing the plugin methods. Is this architecturally bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt plugins normally add properties to the Nuxt context, making them available from a component's `this` without having to explicitly drill into the context like you're doing.

Assuming your plugin [injects](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins#inject-in-root--context) `contentfulClient` like this:

```js
// ~/plugins/contentfulClient.js
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  inject('contentfulClient', {
    async getNotifications() {/*...*/},
    async getTreatments() {/*...*/},
  })
}
```

Then your component could use it like this:

```js
async fetch() {
  this.notifications = await this.$contentfulClient.getNotifications()
  this.treatments = await this.$contentfulClient.getTreatments()
},
```